# dd command to clone an SSD to an NVMe

Tags: dd, nvme

In my windows 10 system, I boot from a 500 GB SSD that has two partitions, both NTFS. I want to clone that to make bootable an internal M.2 NVMe I have installed. At first, I could get it to copy, but after 16 GB it would stop, saying it's out of space. So I used DISKPART in Windows 10 to "clean" the NVMe drive, and now it shows 476.94 GB unallocated (using the disk utility of Win).

But when I boot into Ubuntu (off my thumb drive), the dd command still stops after 16GB saying "No space left on device" and it's referring to the NVMe drive.

Comment: Are you positive you are pointing to the correct drives in `dd`? The correct syntax is `dd if=<source file name> of=<target file name>`, and from what it sounds like you may be pointing the output to your thumb drive.

Comment: gparted lists the m.2 drive as nvme0n1p. So my command is:
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/nvme0n1p status=progress

Comment: If it all possible, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1230481/edit) your question with the output of `lsblk`, as well as the actual error that is being posted in the terminal.

Comment: If you install [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) into your Ubuntu system, you will get help to identify and select the target device. I have tested that mkusb (mkusb version 12 alias mkusb-dus) works with nvme drives.

Comment: `nvme0n1` is a typical device name for an nvme drive. It should not end with p. `nvme0n1p1` is a typical device name for the first partition on an nvme drive.

Comment: Iit is more efficient (and as safe as with mkusb) to use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) for this purpose. Clonezilla is efficient because it is smart enough to identify used blocks in the file systems, and for that reason it can skip free blocks.

Comment: 1. Clonezilla for linux? I'll look into that
2. It didn't in fact write to the USB flash drive. Not only is there nothing like that on the drive, but that drive has 50+ GB free and the error of not enough space came after 16GB.
3. I'll check wither it should be 1p or p1. 4. The actual error was what I quoted, but I'll try lsblk if Clonezilla proves difficult.

Comment: Well, for a Linux noob, Clonezilla is way to difficult. the dd command is simple and easy.. I couldn't even figure out how to launch Clonezilla.

Comment: Just to bring closure: I got a new system, also having a NVMe drive, but now happily use Paragon Drive Manager 17 to clone the running system. I can recommend it both for speed and reliability. The user interface is bad, as it is for so much software nowadays, but not impossible, and you only have to learn it once.